# Using ajax to get the value of simulation

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

index.php

```
    <head>
        <script>
            function getpage(pageName) {
                var obj = new ActiveXObject("msxml2.xmlhttp");
                obj.open("GET", pageName);
                obj.send('A=1&B=2&C=3');
                var txt = obj.responseText;             
                myText.value += txt;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myText"/>
        <input type="button" onclick='getpage("http://localhost/Last/callPageForIE/info.php")';/>
    </body>
</html>
```

info.php

```
<?php
    $A = $_GET['A'];
    $B = $_GET['B'];
    $C = $_GET['C'];

    $sum = $A + $B + $C;
    echo "your sumuatsdion is ".$sum;
?>
```

tried to get the result from info.php but it always give me zero I don't know why, can someone tell me where is my wrong?

Comment: What happens if you var_dump($_GET) in you info.php, are A, B and C the correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing your data as the request *body*. This is what you do for POST requests, not GET requests. GET request data needs to be encoded in a query string in the URL.

```
obj.open("GET", pageName + '?A=1&B=2&C=3');
obj.send();
```

PHP is then casting the undefined variables to `0`.

---

You are also using the obsolete, Microsoft only, ActiveX implementation of XHR. You should switch to the [standard, cross-browser implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead.